# How to update current row on access database table with a print button?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I have a Login form and a data entry form. When a user login, the form will pass its UserID on the next form.

After the user is done filling up the data entry form, he/she needs to print the form and the form will automatically refresh. All the data will be saved on the FormTable so as the UserID that has made the data entry.

My problem is every time I print/save all the data are saved except the UserID has a 0 value. But after the second print/save the previous row's UserID will be updated with the UserID the same is true after the next print/save. I need the UserID field to be updated in real time not 1 row behind.

Here's my code. Can you please help me fix it? Thanks!

```
If Not IsNull(collect) Then
      'sql = "INSERT INTO cedula_tbl (Collector) VALUES ('" & collect & "')"
      sql = "UPDATE cedula_tbl SET collector=('" & collect & "') WHERE cedula_no=DMax('cedula_no', 'cedula_tbl')"

      db.Execute (sql)
 End If
```

Comment: collect holds the value of UserID from the previous form.

Comment: why is this tagged with MySQL if you are using MS Access ?

Comment: There's absolutely no reference to a user ID in your code so there would have to be some magic at work for it to be saved.  If you want a value saved then you have to actually save it.  We can't tell you exactly how to change your code to make it work because we don't know where exactly you expect the user ID to be saved to.